# etcdctl: command not found

Tags: etcd, etcd3

Hi I am using etcd version as follows

**{"etcdserver":"3.2.7","etcdcluster":"3.2.0"}**

I need to get the version history of the key but for me only curl command are working if I do

```
etcdctl get --prefix --rev=4 foo
```

I get:

> -bash: etcdctl: command not found

I am able to run the etcdctl with v2 but with v3 I am getting this error.

Comment: That error means you have installed etcd but not etcdctl. What OS are you using and how did you install etcd?

Answer (score 3):

on ubuntu machine run below to get etcdctl :

### --
apt  install etcd-client

Answer (score 0):

You need to install etcd Binaries

```
]# wget "https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases/download/v3.3.9/etcd-v3.3.9-linux-amd64.tar.gz"
]# tar -xvf etcd-v3.3.9-linux-amd64.tar.gz
]# sudo mv etcd-v3.3.9-linux-amd64/etcd* /usr/local/bin/
]# export ETCDCTL_API=3
```

Then you can execute your etcdl command

Eg:

```
]# /usr/local/bin/etcdctl --endpoints <EnpointIP>:<PORT> --cert=/<location>/<crt>.pem --key=/<location>/<keyFile>.pem --cacert=/<location>/ca.pem member list
```

#### How can I locate my cert file?

If ETCD running as a container follow the below step.

```
1. login to instance where ETCD running.
2. docker ps -a | grep etcd
3. docker inspect <ContainerID> | grep etc
```